# pylint marks error with all imports for libraries installed

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, pylint

I am using **pylint** with **Visual Studio Code**, and it works fine, with the exception that it marks error in all `import` clauses that are not modules from **python** or from my project. It marks error with imports from Django, Django Rest Framework, etc.

[image]
[image]

How can I configure pylint to recognize these libraries that are installed and working (I don't get any error from python)?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the correct Python interpreter.
See the VS Code docs > [Select and activate an environment](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_select-and-activate-an-environment).

Basically:

1. Open the Command Palette (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> or <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+ <kbd>P</kbd>)
2. Enter "**Python: Select Interpreter**"
3. Select the Python environment where *both* Django and pylint is installed
4. Reopen the file

You can confirm the current environment selected from the status bar.

[image]

You can also check it from the workspace's *settings.json*, where a `python.pythonPath` settings gets automatically added/updated every time you switch environments:

```
{
    "python.pythonPath": "/Users/gino/.venvs/test-django/bin/python",
    ...
}
```

Pylint basically checks the currently activated environment for import errors.

If the errors does not instantly disappear, try reloading VS Code.